# MVVMLight Project display XAML string from database in ContentControl

Tags: xaml, binding, contentcontrol

I am working on a Windows Store MVVMLight project. In my XAML View I have a GridView which contains a TextBlock and a ContentControl:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5" Foreground="Red">
    <Run Text="{Binding CategoryDescription}"
         FontSize="18"
         FontWeight="Bold" />                                       
</TextBlock>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBlock>
        <Run FontFamily="Agency FB" FontSize="36" Text="this is item 1"/>
        <LineBreak/>
        <Run FontFamily="Adobe Gothic Std B" Text="this is item 2"/>
        <LineBreak/>
    </TextBlock>
</ContentControl>
```

I would like to get the XAML for the ContentControl to display from the database (the database field CategoryNotes contains the same XAML as the ContentControl above) like I have for the TextBox:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CategoryNotes}">
</ContentControl>
```

However this just displays the XAML as a string as opposed to rendering it as XAML. Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be most appreciated.